# Why I am fail my convert string to a C-string trying this way?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

My code in VS2019 is not working.
In the last line of code compiler throws an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct struct1
{
    string name;
};

void main()
{
    struct1* obj1 = new struct1();
    obj1->name = "Hello";

    // compiler says 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const _Elem *' to 'char [25]'
    char str[25] = (obj1->name).c_str();

}
```

Comment: Initializing arrays just doesn't work that way.

Comment: It's hard to understand when you have a `string` why you would want to copy that to an array. As you have found out arrays are quite limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a pointer to the *start* of the string's character data. You'll need to copy the characters into your array using something like `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot of ways to do this
but first you should change the manner of char array initialization because you made it wrongly.

this is the same program but working

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct struct1
{
    string name;
};



int main()
{
    struct1* obj1 = new struct1();
    obj1->name = "Hello";
    char str[25] = "";
    memcpy(&str,obj1->name.c_str(),obj1->name.size());
    cout << str << endl;
}
```